# Summing items on a nested list f#

Tags: list, recursion, f#, functional-programming

I want to sum each nth element of a list of lists separately. i.e.

```
[[3;2;1]; [4;3;5]] should sum to [7;5;6]
```

All the nested lists have the same length but this length is not known. It is 3 in the example but could be 4, 5 or 6. I know how to do it procedurally but I need a functional solution in F#. Thanks

Comment: Inside your list of lists, do you have a tuple? Or a list? I think you mean this: `[[3;2;1]; [4;3;5]] should sum to [7;5;6]`. Note the semicolon. What you wrote has type `(int * int * int) list list` but probably you want `int int list`.

Comment: Yep, Is it correct now? Sorry, I'm new to F#

Comment: Yes. F# uses `;` to separate array and list elements. You should go through some of the intro series in https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/

Comment: Yeah I've been reading through that. Do you know a way to solve this, do I need to transpose is it like a matrix and sum it?

Comment: you already have two answers :-) You can use `List.transpose` or you can you `List.reduce`. I leave it up to you for a list comprehension type solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compute the sum would be:

```
let sum = List.reduce (List.map2 (+)) vs
```

`reduce` functions combine elements in a sequence using a reducer function. For example:

```
List.reduce (+) [1;2;4]
```

Here `reduce` combines `1` and `2` using `+` which gives `3`. Then `3` is combined with `4` which gives the result `4`.

In OP example we like to reduce a list as well but the elements in input list are themselves lists so the reducer function has to be a bit more complex.

The reducer function given `[3;2;1]` and `[4;3;5]` shall produce `[7;5;6]`. This is piece-wise addition. One way to do it is to use `List.map2`. Normally `map` maps all values in a list using a mapper functions. `map2` allows us to iterate over two input at the same time and map two values into one.

```
List.map2 (+) [3;2;1] [4;3;5]
```

This therefore produces: `[7;5;6]`

The function above has the right signature for a reducer function for `int list list` and the answer is therefore:

```
let sum = List.reduce (List.map2 (+)) vs
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved my assignment from a terrible tragedy :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will make the assumption that your list of lists does not actually contain a tuple inside. So the question should be phrased like this:
`[[3;2;1]; [4;3;5]] should sum to [7;5;6]`. It would be great if you could show a procedural solution as usually it is easy to convert to a [list comprehension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences) for example. But see below for two approaches:

```
let xs = [[3;2;1]; [4;3;5]]

(xs.[0],xs.[1]) ||> List.map2 (+) // val it : int list = [7; 5; 6]

xs 
|> List.transpose
|> List.map List.sum //val it : int list = [7; 5; 6]
```

Comment: I might have meant imperative solution as in c#

Comment: List.transpose in F# ?

Comment: Well, you can show C# code, it can be translated. Yes, `List.transpose` is in `F#`, it has been added recently.